# Displaying a text value in a card that changes depending on today's date in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a date table which has "Date" and the column I'm interested in which is "AcaWeekOfTerm". It also has a "CurWeekOffset" column which is populated with 0 for each date in the current week.

I want a Card visual which shows the AcaWeekOfTerm for today's date, and I want it to change each week.

The pseudocode for what I'm after would be `CurrentAcademicWeek=TextValue of AcademicWeekofTerm where Calendar[WeekOffset]=0`

I can get a card which shows today's Month using `Month(Today())` but that's the closest I've been able to get since.

Note this card should also remain the same regardless of what filters are applied to the report\visualisations.

Any advice would be great

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCD2K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a measure which returns the first nonblank value of the text column you want, with appropriate date filters applied.

If you already have the `CurWeekOffset` field available, then you can use:

```
Current Academic Week = 
CALCULATE ( 
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( DateTable[AcaWeekofYear], 1),
    FILTER ( 
        ALL ( DateTable ),
        DateTable[CurWeekOffset] = 0
    )
)
```

Or you can filter by today's date:

```
Current Academic Week (By Date) = 
CALCULATE ( 
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( DateTable[AcaWeekofYear], 1),
    FILTER ( 
        ALL ( DateTable ),
        DateTable[Date] = TODAY()
    )
)
```

Worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_58655282/